# Focus input after redux dispatch finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am dynamically creating list of inputs with React and Redux. After clicking a button an input is added to the end of list. I need to focus last added input. I tried this code but it focuses penultimate input

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
    onOptionsChange: (newOptions) => {
        dispatch(formActions.updateOptions(newOptions));
    }
});

...
this.props.onOptionsChange({ ...this.props, inputsList}); // change list of inputs
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.inputs[this.props.choices.length - 1]).focus();
```

In logs I can see that focus() is executed before props from state are updated. How can I wait for dispatch to finish?

Comment: can you add the `autoFocus` prop to your input?

Comment: autoFocus look like an interesting choice

Answer (score 4):

**Promisify your dispatch**

Lets write a middleware that returns a promise after completing the dispatch.

```
const thenMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            resolve(next(action));
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
};
```

**Prepare your store first, by installing the middleware**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

/**
 * Our star of the show
 */
const thenMiddleware = store => next => action => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            resolve(next(action));
        } catch(e) {
            reject(e);
        }
    })
};

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thenMiddleware)
);
```

**Now we have to return the dispatch inside our mapDispatchToProps method**

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  onOptionsChange: (newOptions) => {
    return dispatch(formActions.updateOptions(newOptions));
  }
});
```

**Finally hook your event on complete**

Now that you know which input you created last time, 
you can attach an on complete function to this dispatch.

```
this.props.onOptionsChange(newOptions).then(() => {
  // do your input focusing here
});
```

Comment: You don't need to connect it through `mapDispatchToProps` nor can you just `then` the result. His original thunk has to return a `Promise` for this to work.

Comment: @Derk-Jan I wrote a custom middleware to make this happen. Does it look good now?

Comment: It does, except that now someone is FORCED to use a promise. If he returns a promise from his action, it will be wrapped in your middleware :(

You're better off with your initial example and then implementing his formactions.updateOptions function (basically showing the function header, the thunk, return a promise and then adding // [...] original function) or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I would implement `componentDidUpdate` and check the length of your "input-array" or whatever data-structure you are using:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if (prevProps.choices.length < this.props.choices.length) {
      ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.inputs[this.props.choices.length - 1]).focus();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create new wrapping component for `input` element. That component will autofocus, when rendered.

```
class Input extends React.Component {
    keepRef = (ref) => {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.ref.focus();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <input ref={this.keepRef} {...this.props} />
        )
    }
}
```

If you don't want `Input` component to handle focus, move logic to it's parent.

Comment: Or use `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` and do a `!==` check and then focus.

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is not invoked in **first** render!

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similiar problem, wherein, I had a list of items and I need to focus on the last element whenever a new item is added. The below code is using flux architecture but i guess it should solve your problem.

```
addNewItem: function() {
    var self = this;
    var list = this.state.list || {};
    var listOrder = this.state.listOrder || [];
    var newKey = "some_random_key";

    list[newKey] = {
        "product": ""
    };
    listOrder.push(newKey);
    this.state.list = list;
    this.state.listOrder = listOrder;
    this.setState({list: this.state.list, listOrder: this.state.listOrder, showSaveButton: true});
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".buy-form-item-list-row .buy-form-item-list-item-name").last().focus();
    }, 0);
},
```

So in the above code.. 
listOrder contains the keys of list of items. Eg: 
list is an object which contain the item. Eg:

listOrder=[ran_1, ran_2];

list={
  ran_1: {
    product: "Eggs - 5"
  },
  ran_2: {
    product: "Bread - 1"
  }
}

render method, iterate over the listOrder and creates a Input tag with className="buy-form-item-list-item-name" for each item.

The trick to focus on the last item is the setTimeout with an interval of 0. When you call setState it does not trigger render function at that moment itself, instead it waits for the function to execute completely.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Redux !== flux. Using setTimeout is a hack and not a good solution.